# Pandas conditional groupby count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
            'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
     'D' : [2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2]})
```

df

```
    A       D
0   foo     2
1   foo     4
2   foo     4
3   foo     2
4   bar     5
5   bar     4
6   bar     3
7   bar     2
```

I would like to get a count of rows where column A = 'foo' and column D = 2.
I would then like to put the result in a new column like this:

```
#First, I filter
df2=df.loc[(df['A']=='foo')&(df['D']==2)]
#Then, I use groupby and lambda x to count
df['Dcount']=df2.groupby(['D'])['D'].transform(lambda x: x.count())
df
```

And I get this:

```
    A       D   Dcount
0   foo     2   2
1   foo     4   NaN
2   foo     4   NaN
3   foo     2   2
4   bar     5   NaN
5   bar     4   NaN
6   bar     3   NaN
7   bar     2   NaN
```

BUT, I get the "SettingWithCopyWarning":
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

My question is: Does this warning matter in this case? 
Also, how does pandas know to match the rows up correctly if it's taking them from another dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this warning matter in this case?

I see that warning for a lot of things, and it's never once made a difference to me. I just ignore it.

> Also, how does pandas know to match the rows up correctly if it's taking them from another dataframe?

pandas is using the *index* of the DataFrame. Here's your example, rewritten slightly for clarity:

```
df2 = df.query('A=="foo" and D==2')
df2['Dcount'] = len(df2)
```

The resulting DataFrame is

```
     A  D  Dcount
0  foo  2       2
3  foo  2       2
```

Notice the `0` and `3` in the index? That's what pandas uses to the line everything up. So I could just use the above with

```
df['Dcount'] = df2['Dcount']
```

and I will get your same result. The right-hand side of that assignment is a Series, so the index is built-in.

On the other hand, I would get an error is I had tried to assign an array:

```
df['Dcount'] = df2['Dcount'].values  # length error
```