# Pandas Conditional Groupby Count Part 2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this problem:
[Pandas conditional groupby count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363877/pandas-conditional-groupby-count/34363990#34363990)

I would like the result to be this instead:

```
    A       D   Dcount
0   foo     2   2
1   foo     4   2
2   foo     4   2
3   foo     2   2
4   bar     5   NaN
5   bar     4   NaN
6   bar     3   NaN
7   bar     2   NaN
```

What I mean is, if 2 conditions are met (column A = 'foo' and column B = 2),
I'd like for there to be the distinct count of such rows (2) in the Dcount column for all rows of column A = 'foo'.

Can this be modified to allow for the desired result?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
            'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
     'D' : [2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2]})

#First, I filter
df2=df.loc[(df['A']=='foo')&(df['D']==2)]
#Then, I use groupby and lambda x to count
df['Dcount']=df2.groupby(['D'])['D'].transform(lambda x: x.count())
df
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` from `numpy` in a one-liner:

```
import numpy as np

df['Dcount'] = np.where(df['A']=='foo', sum((df.A=='foo') & (df.D==2)), np.NaN)

#In [34]: df
#Out[34]:
#     A  D  Dcount
#0  foo  2       2
#1  foo  4       2
#2  foo  4       2
#3  foo  2       2
#4  bar  5     NaN
#5  bar  4     NaN
#6  bar  3     NaN
#7  bar  2     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to do this for every group in column A?